# Searching contents of files

Tags: lucene

Okay I am planning to create a local search engine in my intranet which searches the contents of files like xls,xlsx,doc,docx,pdb etc.

After searching in internet I am thinking that Luke Lucene can be used for this. Am I right?
Can Lucene be integrated in a Website?

I have around 500 Gb of files can Lucene handle these many files? Is there any alternative?

I know only basics of C and CPP.I dont have any prior knowledge on this. I am a self learner and please suggest me a good book on Lucene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, Lucene can be used for this. But there is some code you need to write yourself (as Lucene is just a library):
- crawling code
- text extraction
- build a searcher app..

so you might be better looking at [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), that is built on top of Lucene, and has many built in features you would use: a solid server you can access with any language and [dih](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) for your crawling needs, and [tika](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) integration for text extraction, among many other things

Comment: Can you suggest me a good book on solr or any online tutorial.

Comment: there are several books now, http://lucene.apache.org/solr/books.html myself I own Apache Solr 3 Enterprise Search Server but it might be a bit outdated nowadays.